# Access localStorage in Flutter Webview

Tags: flutter, webview, local-storage

I am using the official flutter `webview_flutter` package ([pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example)) in order to include a third-party web-app including a javascript library into an example flutter app. When I run the application on my device I get the following error:

```
"Uncaught (in promise) SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs."
```

To integrate the web-app I just copied the example of the `webview_flutter` package on pub.dev and changed the HTML code to the third-party integration code (simply a div element and a js library).

How can I let the webview access the `localStorage` property from `Window`?

Is it related to this issue [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-devtools-experimental/issues/292)?

Answer (score 1):

[This is the issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26133) related on accessing the localStorage property from Window. Unfortunatelly it's still open.